# import pyaudio._portaudio as pa - что и откуда здесь импортируется ? _portaudio такой файл нигде нет

Tags: python, pyaudio

есть импорт, `import pyaudio._portaudio as pa`, никак не могу найти именно файл **_portaudio** в репозитории, нажмите ссылку ниже

[строка: 111](https://github.com/CristiFati/pyaudio/blob/master/src/pyaudio/__init__.py)

подскажите пожалуйста где искать файл **_portaudio**, притом что репозитории почти соответсвует тому коду который у меня в системе...